# Rhino object browser

Tags: javascript, rhino

I'm looking for an object browser (in sense of smalltalk class browser) either desktop or better through web, for Rhino. Could anybody point me to such?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to browse Javascript objects, you should use Firebug's excellent built-in object inspector.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to develop in js using smalltalk/self style of image programming on the server. I don't see how to connect firebug to rhino, but if its possible it would be great.

Comment: The Lively Kernel has a Smalltalk feel but it's client side